# race condition when writing to same file in c

Tags: c, race-condition

i wrote a program to answer [this](https://github.com/posborne/linux-programming-interface-exercises/blob/master/05-file-io-further-details/README.md#exercise-5-3) question
but when i run the program i get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UFby.jpg) result

as of the answer of this exercise, i expect that the volume of the f1 be 2MB but when i run the program the result was 1Mb. can someone explain this difference?

the code was compiled by gcc version 9.3.0 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04).

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int is_append = 1;
    int fd;
    int flags;
    int number_of_bytes;
    char buf = '0';
    off_t offset;
    mode_t mode;


    if (argc < 3 || argv[3] == "help")
    {
        usage_error();
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(4 == argc && strcmp("x", argv[3])) {
        usage_error();
        return -1;
    }
    
    if(4 == argc) { // the x argument is specified
        is_append = 0;
    }

    flags = O_CREAT | (O_APPEND & is_append) | O_WRONLY;
    mode = S_IWUSR | S_IRUSR;

    number_of_bytes = atoi(argv[3]);
    if (number_of_bytes <= 0)
    {
        printf("num-bytes must be grater than 0!\n");
        return -1;
    }
    

    fd = open(argv[3], flags, mode);
    if(-1 == fd) {
        printf("error in open.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < number_of_bytes; i++)
    {
            if(!is_append) {
                offset = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
            }

            if(-1 == write(fd, &buf, 1)) {
                printf("error in write.\n");
                return -1;
            }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `O_APPEND & is_append` is wrong. ‘is_append` is 0 or 1, so `&` yields only a single bit, not the full value of `O_APPEND`.

Comment: In the future, do not include problem statements or results only as links to external images. All information needed for the question should be in the question, not external.

Comment: `argv[3] == "help"` --> Use `strcmp`.

Comment: thansk for reporting my error.

Comment: @EricPostpischil i tried to dont link the problom and results but the site prohibits me. thanks very much for answering my qustion.